# Find person who deleted a branch?

Tags: git, repository, metadata, git-branch

I need to find the person who deleted a branch in a project am working with

By checking the repo folder/files in `.git/refs/heads/`, I can not find any metadata with that information.

What is the work around to find this/ him?

Comment: What is the nature of the repo pushed to? GitHub, BitBucket? privately owned? (the latter probably, if you can inspect its .git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git alone would not provide any audit log for who pushed what.

You would need an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#auth) like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html) in order to log those operations.

Note that if you have access to the remote repo (to which a branch deletion was pushed), you can find trace of the deleted branch in the [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Comment: The reflog *for the branch* gets deleted when you delete the branch. There may (or may not) be information in the `HEAD` reflog, but it won't tell you who deleted the other branch. There have been on and off discussions of having the reflog stick around, which would be useful to allow "undeleting" the branch, but I don't think anyone has attempted to implement this yet (it requires reworking the innards of reflogs).

Comment: @torek yes, I was thinking of the HEAD reflog. And yes, the reflog won't include any user metadata information.

Answer (score 5):

you can view this detail under activity section of org dashboard.
Only org owners have access to this page.

```
https://github.com/orgs/{ORG_NAME}/dashboard
```

Comment: Thank you! This really save my day! By nature git wont let you know such information. But if it's on github then this is the place to look for!

Comment: It's a pity that this shows all activity for all repos in an org. For mine, that is just too much. The part I needed to check gets buried under all the activity in the rest... :-(

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you're using GitLab, you can find all the activity here.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to other answers, I checked the closed pull requests. This way, I found the PR for the branch deleted after merging and by who.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not the original intention, this only tells you if the PR was set to delete the branch automatically, or someone else did it. But the main intention here is that somebody who shouldn't deleted a branch and you want to find out who.