# How to find out who deleted a branch in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

In our Gerrit repository someone deleted a branch. Is there any way to view the person who have deleted that branch. Local reflog not showing the details.

Hi VonC, From this link `https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#get-reflog` i am trying to find the person details through `REST-API`.

```
curl -v -k -H "Authorization: user:<http-password>" -X GET https://gerrit-server/gerrit/projects/core/test-repo/branches/dev/reflog HTTP/1.0
```

But it shows below error.

```
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:59:55 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 19
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Disposition: attachment
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
<
Not found: core
* Connection #0 to host gerrit-server left intact
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Could not resolve host: HTTP
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: HTTP
```

Answer (score 0):

I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584361/6309) that Git alone would not provide adequate audit to find who pushed a branch deletion.

Gerrit itself offers limited audit feature (like [Gerrit 2.12 and its Group audit log](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/2.12.html#group-screen)), or, as mentioned by the OP, [reflog](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#get-reflog).

(Maybe accessing the logs of the Gerrit server listener (SSH or HTTPS server), you might reconcile the possible deletion date with some network access log, but that seems reaching out.)

The OP tries:

```
 GET https://gerrit-server/gerrit/projects/core/test-repo/branches/dev/reflog
```

But that returns 404 and using that API calls must respect:

```
GET /projects/{project-name}/branches/{branch-id}/reflog
```

[It turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880109/how-to-find-out-who-deleted-a-branch-in-gerrit/60880387?noredirect=1#comment107797966_60880387) it was an URL issue:

```
 curl --user user:<http-password> https://gerrit-server/gerrit/a/projects/core%2Ftest-repo/branches/dev/reflog
```

Note the '`/a/`' in `gerrit-server/gerrit/a/projects/...`: it seems mandatory in the OP's case.

Comment: @Kishore Is `core/test-repo` the name of your project? Also can you try without the final HTTP1.0?

Comment: This is our Server URl - `https://gerrit-server/gerrit/` and `core/test-repo`is the repository/project name.

Comment: tried even without `HTTP1.0` at last. still it shows same error.

Comment: @Kishore Then you need to check the gerrit logs. 404 can also means "authentication issue"

Comment: Restapi related error not there in gerrit server `error_log` file.

Comment: @Kishore Is there any other log file/error message at the time of the rest query?

Comment: No error message in other logs as well. i have gerrit admin permission. still unable to fetch the data.

Comment: Then, if no authentication error pops up, maybe the URL is somehow not the right one. That of the reflog feature is not available in your Gerrit version?

Comment: i am using Gerrit version - `2.16.17`.my project name is `core/test-repo` when i run curl command it says `Not found: core`, but my URl is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210577/discussion-between-vonc-and-kishore).

Comment: VonC, It was URL issue. i have changed the URL to `curl --user user:<http-password> https://gerrit-server/gerrit/a/projects/core%2Ftest-repo/branches/dev/reflog` and it worked.

Comment: @Kishore Great! I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Kishore I wonder why `/a/projects` instead of `/projects` though...

Comment: if i dont include `/a/projects/` it is not working. showing error as not found.

Comment: @Kishore OK, but I wonder where the /a/ is coming from. NGiNX? I don't see a /a/ in the Gerrit API page. https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.16.17/rest-api-projects.html

Comment: I tried it on two different gerrit servers(one with nginx & another without). in both `/a/projects/ required.

Comment: @Kishore Interesting. I had no idea '/a/' was important or required. Thank you.

Comment: Yes true. But many thanks for your continue support. You have helped me in various quires. Thank you!!